# Alert runs when all selectboxes are not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 select boxes that need to be checked.If every one of them is selected before I click the create button. If the five of them are not filled, the click event doesn't work.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on("click", "#createButton", function () {

    if ($('option:selected', '#getSource').attr("typesource") == 1 ){
        console.log('test google');

        var checkDomain = $('#changeDomain').val() != "";
        var checkSource = $('#getSource').val() != "";
        var checkCountries = $('#getCountries').val() != "";
        var checkBundle = $('#getBundle').val() != "";
        var checkPool = $('#getPool').val() != "";

        if (checkDomain && checkSource && checkCountries && checkBundle && checkPool) {
            alert('button works');

            checkDomain = $('#changeDomain').val();
            checkSource = $('#getSource').val();
            checkCountries = $('#getCountries').val();
            checkBundle = $('#getBundle').val();
            checkPool = $('#getPool').val();

            console.log(checkDomain, checkSource, checkCountries, checkBundle, checkPool);
        }
    }
});
```

The alert runs when the last two checkboxes (checkBundle, checkPool) are still empty and when checkDomain, Source and Countries have an option selected.

**HTML**

```
<!--DOMAIN-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
                            <p class="bulkFilters">DOMAIN</p>
                        </div>
                        <select id="changeDomain" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
                            <option value="">Select Domain</option>
                            <?php echo $selectboxDomains;?>
                        </select>
                    </div><!--end col-md-2-->
                    <!--SOURCE-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
                            <p class="bulkFilters">SOURCE</p>
                        </div>
                        <select id="getSource" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
                        </select>
                    </div><!--end col-md-2-->
                    <!--COUNTRY-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
                            <p class="bulkFilters">COUNTRY</p>
                        </div>
                        <select id="getCountries" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
                        </select>
                    </div><!--end col-md-2-->
                    <!--BUNDLE-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
                            <p class="bulkFilters">BUNDLE</p>
                        </div>
                        <select id="getBundle" class="form-control chosen-select" id="source" name="geoFilter[]">
                        </select>
                    </div><!--end col-md-2-->
                    <!--POOL-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
                            <p class="bulkFilters">POOL</p>
                        </div>
                        <select id="getPool" class="form-control chosen-select" id="source" name="geoFilter[]">
                        </select>
                    </div><!--end col-md-2-->
```

If you guys also have any tips for improving my code, I appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: share html also

Comment: okay now you have html

Comment: Your code work just fine :  https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/383/

Comment: For me it's not entirely working, i don't understand why. I test my code by selecting the selectbox one by one and click the button next. When I get to the country select, the alert i prepared runs. :/ but here is working, I don't know why! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#createButton').on("click", function () {

if ($('option:selected', '#getSource').attr("typesource") == 1 ){
    console.log('test google');

    var checkDomain;
    var checkSource;
    var checkCountries;
    var checkBundle;
    var checkPool;
    var err=0;
    $('.chosen-select').each(function(){
       if($(this).val()==""){
          err++;
       }
   });
   if(err===0){
        alert('button works');
        checkDomain = $('#changeDomain').val();
        checkSource = $('#getSource').val();
        checkCountries = $('#getCountries').val();
        checkBundle = $('#getBundle').val();
        checkPool = $('#getPool').val();

        console.log(checkDomain, checkSource, checkCountries, checkBundle, checkPool);
    }
    else{

    }
}
}
```

1.Check if every checkbox has been selected using jquery .each() function
2.Increment `err` if it has no value.
3.If `err==0` proceed

Comment: Could you explain your answer, please? Why this solution?

Comment: It will iterate through your select elements and if anything not selected it will increment the `err`..Isn't it what you desired? @Timmy

Comment: well, yes. I asked for better understanding your solution. Btw, i have an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null`

Comment: My mistake ,you don't need `trim()` just try my edited code,I'll add the explanation,Sorry for the inconvenience @Timmy

Comment: The button works with only one input selected, that is not what I pretend. :/

Comment: The domain select box has content called with ajax. After implementing you code, the ajax stoped working properly. :/

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34091/)**.

Your code will work just fine if you set up a correct click event, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#createButton", function () {

    if ($('option:selected', '#getSource').attr("typesource") == 1 ){
        console.log('test google');

        var checkDomain = $('#changeDomain').val() != "";
        var checkSource = $('#getSource').val() != "";
        var checkCountries = $('#getCountries').val() != "";
        var checkBundle = $('#getBundle').val() != "";
        var checkPool = $('#getPool').val() != "";

        if (checkDomain && checkSource && checkCountries && checkBundle && checkPool) {
            alert('button works');

            checkDomain = $('#changeDomain').val();
            checkSource = $('#getSource').val();
            checkCountries = $('#getCountries').val();
            checkBundle = $('#getBundle').val();
            checkPool = $('#getPool').val();

            console.log(checkDomain, checkSource, checkCountries, checkBundle, checkPool);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="createButton">Submit</button>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
    <p class="bulkFilters">DOMAIN</p>
  </div>
  <select id="changeDomain" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
    <option value="">Select Domain</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->
<!--SOURCE-->
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
    <p class="bulkFilters">SOURCE</p>
  </div>
  <select id="getSource" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
    <option value="">Select SOURCE</option>
    <option value="1" typesource='1'>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->
<!--COUNTRY-->
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
    <p class="bulkFilters">COUNTRY</p>
  </div>
  <select id="getCountries" class="form-control chosen-select" name="geoFilter[]">
    <option value="">Select COUNTRY</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->
<!--BUNDLE-->
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
    <p class="bulkFilters">BUNDLE</p>
  </div>
  <select id="getBundle" class="form-control chosen-select" id="source" name="geoFilter[]">
    <option value="">Select BUNDLE</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->
<!--POOL-->
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="bulkFiltersDiv">
    <p class="bulkFilters">POOL</p>
  </div>
  <select id="getPool" class="form-control chosen-select" id="source" name="geoFilter[]">
    <option value="">Select POOL</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><!--end col-md-2-->
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant my JS code. It's updated now. I forgot to show you my click event for you to check properly :) could you check please?

Comment: I've updated my answer with your click event code and it works just fine.. you could see that the alert will not run until all the selects are empty, i think the problem comes from the default values of those selects (check please this point).